# Blender 2.8 view material transparency and textures at the sametime with Workbench

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view, workbench-render-engine

I am using Blender 2.8 Workbench and trying to visualize some materials which have transparency and others which use an image texture. I can see transparent materials when I use material rendering and image textures when I render the texture, however is there a way to view both at the same time?

One way I have been able to achieve this is to render the textures independently and overlay them afterwards in gimp over the material render pass. However, is there perhaps another way to see both in the viewport? If not, is there a way to automate both render passes and use the compositor to combine them?

many thanks in advance!

Jesse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for future readers:

this is no longer an issue and has been resolved https://developer.blender.org/T63077

happy blending

Jesse

Answer (score 2):

Also for anyone new to Workbench and wanting to use transparency, in your object's material, go to *Viewport Display > Color*, click the color swatch, and then choose an alpha value here.